# How to move AdSense block in responsive website?

Tags: google-adsense, responsive-webdesign, google-adsense-policies

Making my website responsive I've faced the challenge - I need to move AdSense block, for examlpe: in desktop version of website AdSense adblock is located **below** the first post of my blog, but in the mobile version - **above** the first post of my blog.

Usually it's easily solved by using css `@media` queries  for hiding/showing one of blocks (the one above or the one below). But can I make it with AdSense blocks?

These blocks will have the same slot-id. I think that is breaking the adsense google policy. What alternatives are there to fix this?

Comment: Great question! I too am working on a responsive design and probably will need to know this... ;-)